# Can't record or share my screen

Tags: linux, display, gnome, gnu-screen

Hi guys I face a problem, I can't share my entire screen on discord or any platform.
It just goes black and no one can see anything except my mouse pointer!

The problem is not on discord only but I can't record my entire screen with any application except built-in Gnome-shell extension to record my screen.
I'm facing this problem since using gnome shell.

Is there any fix except turning back to mate?

PS : I can share windows only on discord and stuff, I'm using Parrot OS with Gnome extension to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while I asking here and there I switched from default gnome to gnome-xorg and it just works perfectly now !

you just have to logout from your account and search for the little setting to change desktop environment to gnome-xorg !

thanks <3